# Decode a Base64 string in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, base64

I'm new in objecive-C and i would like to decode a NSString encoded in Base64.

Have you any idea to help me?

NSString encoded:

> eyJjbGUiOiJwOW5oOTk3eDRxdhpnZzciLCJ1cmwiOiJtbGtqcW1sa3FzbWxmbXFsanFkln0

NSString i try to find:

> {"cle":"p9nh997x4qvgg7","url":"mlkjqmlkqsmlfmqljqd}

Comment: Now I ask OP and myself too: I'm wondering whether it would have been ***really so much friggin' difficult to google "Base-64 Objective-C"?***

Comment: And btw. it is #3 it the [objective-c] faq.

Comment: LOL @Almo went to google, typed "Decode Base64 Objective-C" and this page was the first result!

Comment: Hahaha!!! Google is kind of funny that way!

Answer (score 5):

get a base64 library: https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64

Create NSData from the string:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:string];
```

convert that data to a string

```
NSString *convertedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Just one rectification : it's "NSUTF8StringEncoding" and not "NSUTF8Encoding".

Comment: ah right, sorry. i rely on auto-complete too much i guess