# NSString - decoding UTF8 string

Tags: ios, utf8-decode

I have a `NSString` object that contains, for example, the encoded string : `Tm8gMQ==`

Because I recover a `NSString` object and not an `NSData` object, how am I suppose to `decode` it ?

Thank you.

Comment: This looks like `Base64` encoded, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648825/decode-a-base64-string-in-objective-c

Comment: This is Base64. Using http://www.base64decode.org/, `Tm8gMQ==` decodes as `No 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used [NSDATA-BASE64 extension](https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64)

```
NSString *nice=@"Tm8gMQ==";
NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:nice];
NSString *convertedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",convertedString);
```

Output

```
2013-06-13 17:23:58.467 Cool[5395:11303] No 1
```