# Converting a Base64 string in an asynchronous call in IOS

Tags: session, ios7, asynchronous, base64

I have this NSURLSessionDataTask and I'm getting a Base64 string from the completionHandler. I'm having trouble converting it back into plaintext using the NS Encoding libraries even after looking up various posts.

[Decode a Base64 string in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648825/decode-a-base64-string-in-objective-c) , 
[Base64 Decoding in iOS 7+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088231/base64-decoding-in-ios-7) , 
[Convert between UIImage and Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios)

String from completionHandler^(Data) = InsnYWN0aW9uJzondGVzdCcsICdpbnB1dCc6J3Rlc3QnfSI=

Code used to try and decode:

```
NSString *baseString =[data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding76CharacterLineLength];
```

I was hoping someone could lead me in the right direction. Thanks.

Full Function - inspired by (http://hayageek.com/ios-nsurlsession-example/):

```
-(void) httpPostWithCustomDelegate
{
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"];
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSData * params =[@"{'action':'test', 'input':'test'}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString * newParams = [params base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[newParams dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                       //NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                       if(error == nil)
                                                       {
                                                           NSString *baseString =[data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding76CharacterLineLength];
                                                           //NSString *baseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                           NSLog(@"Data = %@",baseString);
                                                       }

                                                   }];

[dataTask resume];
```

}

Comment: Show a bit more code to provide more context.

Comment: rmaddy hope the update helps, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`data` contains the base64 encoded string (which represented data that represented some original object). So you need to convert `data` to the actual `NSData` representing whatever it was that was originally encoded.

Basically you need to reverse the original encoding steps.

If you are using iOS 7 or later you can do:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        //NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
        if (data) {
            NSData *originalData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedData:data options:0];
            // Do something with the decoded data
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
        }
}];
```